# LinkItem external links converts to internal url

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

When adding a external url on my LinkItemCollection, EpiServer converts it to a internal page. Is there a way to disable this function?

Using Episerver 7.

Comment: How are you adding the link?

Comment: To a LinkItems external Url: www.mysite.se but when publishing EpiServer changes to an internal page e.g My startpage

Comment: We do this because the page URL might change and if we're trying to help out by making sure the link will continue working in that case. Can you explain a bit more about what you'd like to achieve without a content reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkItem` require you to invoke the method `ToMappedLink` or `ToPermanentLink` when working with external links.

https://world.episerver.com/documentation/class-library/?documentId=cms/7/ac6ab436-b0bb-3f26-dce4-b79230339d79

[image]

Comment: Yes but can i override those methods so it doesnt convert to internal episerver pages when the url matches the host name. If yes, how?